# What are the different behaviors of `daw` and is there a difference between a `word` and a `WORD` (based on docs)?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Consider the sentence

> The sky is very blue today.

Let's investigate what happens when we use the vim command `daw` with the cursor placed at different positions.

1. Cursor at any character of "blue"

`The sky is very today`

If we were to add a bunch of spaces between "blue" and "today", `daw` would still give this same result. It seems like `daw` deletes the word the cursor is in plus trailing whitespace.

2. Cursor at any character of "today"

> The sky is very blue.

In this case, it seems `daw` deleted the word and leading whitespace.

If we were to add a space between "today" and the period, then `daw` would behave like case 1).

Now, the help documentation for `aw` says

> "a word", select [count] words (see word). Leading or trailing white
> space is included, but not counted.

I would have expected `daw` to delete the word and trailing and leading whitespace based on this documentation.

**What are, after all, the different cases in which `daw` has distinctive behavior?**

When I look at the documentation for `word` I see the following information

> A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
> sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space
> (spaces, tabs, ).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword'
> option.  An empty line is also considered to be a word.
> A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
> space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.

From the wording here, I am not sure if there is a distinction between `word` and `WORD` or not. They seem to be the same thing (in which case, why the two entries in the documentation?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How `aw` (not `daw`) handles leading and trailing whitespace is unrelated to `word` or `WORD` so there is no reason to bring them up. The difference between `word` and `WORD` only matters when comparing `aw` and `iw` to `aW` and `iW`, which is off topic.

`aw` must be considered in contrast with `iw`: if `iw` covers `blue`, then what should `aw` cover? The answer is relatively obvious: "what `iw` covers, plus leading/trailing whitespace".

But how to handle that whitespace? If we systematically trim whitespace from both the front and the back, we leave the text in a poor state:

```
The sky is very blue today.
               ^^^^^^
The sky is verytoday.
```

In order to avoid situations like this, Vim uses a simple algorithm that can be summarized like this:

- if the word is surrounded by whitespace, then cover the word + trailing whitespace,

  ```
  The sky is very blue today.
                  ^^^^^
  ```
- if the word only has trailing whitespace, then cover the word + trailing whitespace,

  ```
  The sky is very blue today.
  ^^^^
  ```
- if the word only has leading whitespace, then cover the word + leading whitespace,

  ```
  The sky is very blue today.
                      ^^^^^^
  ```
- if the word is not surrounded by whitespace, then only cover the word.

Answer (score 1):

About word vs. WORD:

To understand word you must group the character set into three families:

1. Spaces (tab or space)
2. Normal character (defined by `iskeyword`)
3. The rest (typically punctuation)

A word is a contiguous sequence of the last two family of characters (Normal, The rest)

Here is what the doc explain it (`:help word`):

```
A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
tabs, <EOL>).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
is also considered to be a word.
```

To understand WORD you must group the character set into two families:

1. Spaces (tab or space)
2. The rest

A WORD is a contiguous sequence the last family of characters (The rest)

Here is what the doc explain it (`:help WORD`):

```
A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.
```

e.g alpha-blondy is three words but only one WORD.

About the behavior of `daw` you are right:

- The spaces before the word are deleted if it is the last word of the line
- The spaces before the word are deleted otherwise

For `daW` the logic is the same but with WORD instead of word

- The spaces before the WORD are deleted if it is the last word of the line
- The spaces before the WORD are deleted otherwise

Here is what the documentation says (`:help 04.8`)

```
The "d" of "daw" is the delete operator.  "aw" is a text object.  Hint: "aw"
stands for "A Word".  Thus "daw" is "Delete A Word".  To be precise, the white
space after the word is also deleted (or the white space before the word if at
the end of the line).
```